# Creating a numpy python string array with pybind11

Tags: pybind11

I am trying to modify a numpy string array from c++ with pybind11. The code i am using has the following structure:

```
py::array_t<py::str> process_array(py::array_t<py::str> input);

PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(fast_calc, m) {
  m.def("process_array", process_array);
}

py::array_t<py::str> process_array(py::array_t<py::str> input) {
  auto buf = input.request();
  cout << &buf;

  return input;
}
```

The problem i face is this error message:

**pybind11/numpy.h:1114:19: error: static assertion failed: Attempt to use a non-POD or unimplemented POD type as a numpy dtype
     static_assert(is_pod_struct::value, "Attempt to use a non-POD or unimplemented POD type as a numpy dtype");**

Not sure whats the catch. In python you can create numpy string arrays so what am i doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: From first sight it seems that string arrays are not supported (I'm only a pybind user and did not look in detail). I would suggest that you list your questions to the [developers](https://gitter.im/pybind/Lobby)

Answer (score 3):

Fixed length strings are supported in pybind11 (tested on v2.2.3, CentOS7, python3.6.5) by using the `pybind11::array_t< std::array<char, N> >` or `char[N]` type. Likely you'll want to pad out the string with null values just in case, as the standard pitfalls of C-style strings apply (e.g. N-1 useable characters). I prefer working with `std::array` as it doesn't decay to a `char*` without calling `.data()` making your intentions clearer to other readers.

So some psuedocode would look like this for a vector of 16 byte strings:

```
using np_str_t = std::array<char, 16>;
pybind11::array_t<np_str_t> cstring_array(vector.size());
np_str_t* array_of_cstr_ptr = reinterpret_cast<np_str_t*>(cstring_array.request().ptr);

for(const auto & s : vector)
{
   std::strncpy(array_of_cstr_ptr->data(), s.data(), array_of_cstr_ptr->size());
   array_of_cstr_ptr++;
}

return cstring_array; //numpy array back to python code
```

And then in python:

```
array([b'ABC', b'XYZ'], dtype='|S16')
```